# Regex .NET match everything until first space + letter is found

Tags: .net, regex

I have:

```
01 - Radio N Am 2007 
186508980X -16-17 - Horns and Bones
(ab)normal - constitutions
```

Goal:

```
Radio N Am 2007 
Horns and Bones
constitutions
```

I tried with

```
^(?:(?!(?:\S*[\s[a-z][A-Z])).)+
```

but the output is:

```
 - Radio N Am 2007
 - Horns and Bones
```

Please help me with a correct regex to achieve the goal.

Comment: I think you just need to use `Substring` with `LastIndexOf("-") + 1` unless you precise the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to replace, match what you want with:

```
(?<= )[A-Za-z].*
```

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%20)%5BA-Za-z%5D.*&i=01%20-%20Radio%20N%20Am%202007%20%0D%0A186508980X%20-16-17%20-%20Horns%20and%20Bones%0D%0A(ab)normal%20-%20constitutions)

Answer (score 1):

Search for:

```
^.*?- (?=[A-Za-z])
```

and replace by empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kH0kA6/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a regex solution that will only match the substrings after the last `-`, you can just use

```
-\s*([^-]*$)
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=-%5Cs*(%5B%5E-%5D*%24)&i=01%20-%20Radio%20N%20Am%202007%20%0D%0A186508980X%20-16-17%20-%20Horns%20and%20Bones%0D%0A(ab)normal%20-%20constitutions&o=m)

If there **must be a letter after the hyphen**, you may use `-\s*(\p{L}[^-]*$)`. The `\p{L}` construct will match any Unicode letter.

[image]

[C# IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/3Z8woC):

```
var lines = new string[] {"01 - Radio N Am 2007", 
"186508980X -16-17 - Horns and Bones",
"(ab)normal - constitutions"};
foreach (string s in lines) 
{
    var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"-\s*([^-]*$)");
    foreach (Match m in matches)
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

But you can also use a non-regex approach if you need to get substrings after the last hyphen:

```
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("-") + 1).Trim());
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/dmlOBy)